# Auzre Java SDK equivalent for NamespaceManager.RevokePublisher (Servicebus / EventHub publisher revocation list management)

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-java-sdk

We are searching for a way to programmatically manage the EventHub publisher revocation list with the Azure Java SDK. The .NET SDK has the [NamespaceManager.RevokePublisher method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.revokepublisher?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_RevokePublisher_System_String_System_String_) in the ServiceBus namespace, that is actually tailored to EventHub publisher revocation.

After a long search we are not able to find an equivalent method in the Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for management operations in the current generation of the Event Hubs client library for Java.  I believe the easiest approach to do this programmatically would be calling the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/eventhub/revoke-publisher).

For what its worth, the same is true of .NET and other languages; the documentation that you've referenced is for a legacy package that predates the current Azure security direction.  More recently, Azure has been focused on segmenting the data and management operations into independent security contexts which do not share overlapping permissions.